# Laravel 4 benchmark my queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It seems like Profiler is not with Laravel 4 anymore.
What is the best way to know how long all the queries on the function took to execute?

I wanted to compare 2 different codes of the same function and see which approach is faster.

Eloquent VS Query Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use "[Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork)". As Github note says:
Clockwork is a Chrome extension for PHP development, extending Developer Tools with a new panel providing all kinds of information useful for debugging and profiling your PHP applications, including information about request, headers, get and post data, cookies, session data, database queries, routes, visualisation of application runtime and more.

Give it a look, it's great! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are some profilers for Laravel 4 around, this is one: https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler.

Here's how you would use it:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{

    Profiler::startTimer('testLogging');
    $data = User::all();
    Profiler::endTimer('testLogging');

    Profiler::startTimer('testLogging');
    $data = DB::table('users')->get();
    Profiler::endTimer('testLogging');

});
```

This is another nice one: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. Looks like the old Laravel 3 profiler.